# Input string was not in a correct format while storing data in my database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am having a web page like this

name: [TextBox]

Enter password:[TextBox]    [Label]  [Label]

Enter password:[TextBox]    [Label]  [Label]

Similarly 3 more TextBox's to capture password from user .....i am actually trying to calculate the the time the user requires to enter the same password in each  textbox...

so i did this....

```js
function focusFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("TextBox2").style.background = "yellow";
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("Label2").innerText = (d.getTime() % 10000000);
}
```

and using blurFunction to calculate the time till the user remains on this textbox

```js
function blurFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("TextBox2").style.background = "red";
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("Label7").innerText = (d.getTime() % 10000000);
}
```

similarly for other textboxes
 and on button click trying to store this in my database

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {


  string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBMS"].ConnectionString;
  using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)) {

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegisterUser", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time1", int.Parse(Label7.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time2", int.Parse(Label8.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time3", int.Parse(Label9.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time4", int.Parse(Label10.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time5", int.Parse(Label11.Text));
    con.Open();
    int ReturnCode = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (ReturnCode == -1) {
      Label12.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      Label12.Text = "User Name already in Use , Please use another user name";
    }

  }
}
```

then it is running successfully and even showing on each label different time of Entering and Exiting but on Button click it is showing this Error " Input string was not in a correct format" at this position.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time1", int.Parse(Label7.Text));
```

i had used this stored procedure

```
create proc spRegisterUser        
@UserName nvarchar(100),        
@Password nvarchar(100),        
@time1 int,    
@time2 int,    
@time3 int,    
@time4 int,    
@time5 int        
as        
Begin        

 Declare @count int         
 Set @Count = (@time1 + @time2 + @time3 + @time4 + @time5)/5         

 Begin        

  --Change: Column list specified while inserting      
  Insert into register       
  values  (@UserName, @Password, @time1,@time2,@time3,@time4,@time5,@count)        
 End        

 End
```

Comment: What is the value of `Label7.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: like when my focus comes to textbox2 then label 2 value comes out to be 4997660  and when i enter some text in this Textbox and move to next Textbox then my label7 value comes out to be 5003309..... and to calculate the time i was trying to take the diffrence between the two ie. 5003309-4997660=5649...